Deriving Properties of the Random Walk
I am trying to work on the following question about deriving the mean and variance of a random walk. I tried to do this without looking at the true answer.
Suppose I have a general random walk (discrete time). Let $X_n$ be the position of the random walk after n steps, starting at $X_0 = 0$. For each step:
$$
X_n = X_{n-1} + Y_n
$$
Where $Y_n$ is the step taken at time n, defined as:
$$
Y_n = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{with probability } p \\
-1 & \text{with probability } 1-p
\end{cases}
$$
I think I can derive the Mean and Variance:

Mean : This should be just the expected value at each step and then the expectation of the sum of expectations:

$$
E[Y_n] = (+1 \cdot p) + (-1 \cdot (1-p)) = p - (1-p) = 2p - 1
$$
$$
E[X_n] = E[X_0 + Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n] = E[X_0] + E[Y_1] + E[Y_2] + ... + E[Y_n]
$$
$$
E[X_n] = 0 + n(2p - 1) = n(2p - 1)
$$

Variance: Using first principles (i.e. variance-expectation relationship), I should be able to extend the results from the mean to calculate the variance in the same way:

$$
Var(Y_n) = E[Y_n^2] - (E[Y_n])^2 = (+1^2 \cdot p) + (-1^2 \cdot (1-p)) - (2p-1)^2
$$
$$
Var(Y_n) = p + (1-p) - (4p^2 - 4p + 1) = 1 - 4p^2 + 4p - 1 = 4p(1-p)
$$
Now, for the position after n steps:
$$
X_n^2 = (X_0 + Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n)^2
$$
Expanding this and taking the expectation:
$$
E[X_n^2] = E[X_0^2] + E[Y_1^2] + E[Y_2^2] + ... + E[Y_n^2] + 2E[X_0(Y_1 + ... + Y_n)] + 2E[\sum_{i<j} Y_iY_j]
$$
Note that:

$E[X_0^2] = 0$
$E[Y_i^2] = 1$ for all $i$
$E[X_0(Y_1 + ... + Y_n)] = 0$.
$E[Y_iY_j] = E[Y_i]E[Y_j] = (2p-1)^2$ for $i \neq j$.

Therefore:
$$
E[X_n^2] = n + n(n-1)(2p-1)^2
$$
Now we can calculate the variance:
$$
Var(X_n) = E[X_n^2] - (E[X_n])^2 = n + n(n-1)(2p-1)^2 - n^2(2p-1)^2
$$
$$
Var(X_n) = n + n(n-1)(2p-1)^2 - n^2(2p-1)^2 = n - n(2p-1)^2 = n(1 - (2p-1)^2) = 4np(1-p)
$$
To summarize everything:

Mean: $E[X_n] = n(2p - 1)$
Variance: $Var(X_n) = 4np(1-p)$

Is my reasoning correct?

Additional justifications:

$E[X_0^2] = 0$

This is true because we defined the starting position $X_0 = 0$. Therefore:
$$
E[X_0^2] = E[0^2] = E[0] = 0
$$

$E[Y_i^2] = 1$ for all $i$

This is true because $Y_i$ can only take values of +1 or -1. Squaring either of these values always results in 1. Therefore:
$$
E[Y_i^2] = (+1^2 \cdot p) + (-1^2 \cdot (1-p)) = p + (1-p) = 1
$$

$E[X_0(Y_1 + ... + Y_n)] = 0$

This is true because $X_0 = 0$, so any product involving $X_0$ will be zero:
$$
E[X_0(Y_1 + ... + Y_n)] = E[0 \cdot (Y_1 + ... + Y_n)] = E[0] = 0
$$

$E[Y_iY_j] = E[Y_i]E[Y_j] = (2p-1)^2$ for $i \neq j$

Note that for $i \neq j$, $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent random variables. My way of looking at this is because at each step, $Y_i$ is determined by a separate, independent random event. The probability of moving up (+1) or down (-1) at any step is always $p$ and $1-p$ respectively, regardless of what happened in previous steps or what will happen in future steps.
For independent random variables, the expectation of their product is equal to the product of their expectations:
$$
E[Y_iY_j] = E[Y_i]E[Y_j]
$$
Now, we've previously calculated that for any step:
$$
E[Y_i] = (+1 \cdot p) + (-1 \cdot (1-p)) = p - (1-p) = 2p - 1
$$
Therefore:
$$
E[Y_iY_j] = E[Y_i]E[Y_j] = (2p-1)(2p-1) = (2p-1)^2
$$

The calculations are alright.
For Variance part, after obtaining $Var[Y_i] = 4p(1-p)$, you can directly apply like this
$$ Var[X_n] = Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n Var[Y_i] 
= \sum_{i=1}^n 4p(1-p) = 4np(1-p) $$
The first equality we just dropped $X_0$ as that is a constant.
The second equality is due to the independence of $Y_i$; In general,
$$ Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n Var[Y_i] + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n Cov[Y_i, Y_j] $$
Due to independence, the covariance terms vanish in this case.

thank you so much for your answer! So our variance calculations both end up the same?

Yes you also obtained $4np(1-p)$
